# Converting VARCHAR to Date using TO_DATE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a set of data where the col is VARCHAR() but I need it to be in DATE format.

I was trying to do it as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE df_new
    AS SELECT
col1 AS NAME
col2 AS first_name
col3 AS last_name
,TO_DATE(col4, 'yyyymmdd') AS date
FROM df_old
```

but I am getting an error "Can't parse '' as date with format 'yyyymmdd'".

I have tried messing with the input for the date format (such as 'yyyy/mm/dd') but I am pretty new to SQL so I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Snowflake is a very different DBMS product than PostgreSQL. Which one are you really using? There is no `create or replace table` in Postgres, so apparently it's Snowflake not Postgres

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The assignment said it is LIKE PostgreSQL. I misinterpreted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE df_new
    AS SELECT
col1 AS NAME
,col2 AS first_name
,col3 AS last_name
,CASE WHEN col4 = '' THEN NULL ELSE TO_DATE(col4, 'YYYY-MM-DD') END AS date
FROM df_old
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`TRY_TO_DATE`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html), it will return NULL for values where it can't parse the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that all of your values other than NULLs are of the string 'yyyymmdd' then the following will work in snowflake.

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(datekey),'yyyymmdd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some of your col4 entries are NULL or empty strings. Try maybe

```
... FROM df_old WHERE col4 ~ '[0-9]{8}'
```

to select only valid inputs. To be clear, if you give the format as 'YYYYMMDD' (you should use uppercase) an entry in col4 has to look like '20190522'.

Comment: I think you're 100% right about why I am receiving the error being the NULL values that DO exist. The problem now when adding in the REGEXP_LIKE is that nothing populates in the rows. I will keep messing with it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah sorry I was a bit hasty by using Oracle syntax, if you're on Postgres you'll want to use the ~ operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

All dates are stored in an internal format. 
You cannot influence how a date is STORED. However you have it format it the way you want when you pull the data from the database via query.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by the following:

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE df_new
AS SELECT
,col1 AS NAME
,col2 AS first_name
,col3 AS last_name
,CASE WHEN "col4" = '' then NULL ELSE TO_DATE(col4, 'YYYYMMDD') AS date
FROM df_old